# circular linked list problem in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, circular-list

Why doesn't my linked list code work? It has no problem with 4 notes, but when I get to 5 the sorted linked list seems to hang. Does it not know where to append and place the new node?

I mean,for example the first data is a name starts with letter A, and the second start with  D and the 3rd start with C.. but when i enter for the 5th, letter I or K.. my system like hang or something..

#### Node

```
Node * next;
Node * prev;
userData * data;
```

#### List

```
Node * start;
Node * end;
```

#### Function that ads a new node in alphabetical order

```
void addUserData(userData * data){
        string name = data->getName();
        Node* node = new Node(data);

        if(isEmpty()){
            start = node;
            end = node;
            start->Next(end);
            end->Prev(start);
            return;
        }
        else if(!isEmpty() && start == end){
            node->Next(start);
            node->Prev(start);
            start->Next(node);
            start->Prev(node);

            end = node;

            if(start->getUserData()->getName().compare(node->getUserData()->getName())>0){
                end = start;
                start = node;
            }
            return;
        }
        else{
            Node *temp = start;
            if(name.compare("N") < 0){
                while(temp->getNext()->getNext()!=NULL && name.compare(temp->getNext()->getUserData()->getName())>0){
                    temp = temp ->getNext();
                }
            }
            else{
                temp = end;
                while(name.compare(temp->getUserData()->getName())<0){
                    temp = temp ->getPrev();
                }

            }
            if(name.compare(temp->getUserData()->getName())>0){
                node ->Next(temp->getNext());
                node ->Prev(temp);

                temp->Next(node);
                node->getNext()->Prev(node);

                if(name.compare(end->getUserData()->getName())>0){
                    end = node;

                }

            }else if(name.compare(temp->getUserData()->getName())<0){
                node->Next(temp);
                node->Prev(temp->getPrev());

                temp->getPrev()->Next(node);
                temp->Prev(node);

                if(name.compare(start->getUserData()->getName())<0){
                    start = node;
                }

            }else{
                cout<<"Name already exist\n";

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried running your code through the debugger?  I can't see how the debugger won't show you exactly why your code is not behaving right given the specific input data that you give it.

Comment: So much wrong with this it's hard to count. Mainly, you're constructing the list as circular (both after the first and second inserts), but when you scan the list you're checking to see whether the pointers are null.

Comment: @user708280: one note about strings, `lhs < rhs` is generally easier to read that `lhs.compare(rhs) < 0`. The easier is reading the source code, the easier is debugging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this section:

```
if(name.compare("N") < 0){
  while(temp->getNext()->getNext()!=NULL && name.compare(temp->getNext()->getUserData()->getName())>0){
    temp = temp ->getNext();
  }
}
else{
  temp = end;
  while(name.compare(temp->getUserData()->getName())<0){
    temp = temp ->getPrev();
  }
}
```

1. Yoiu have some untidy logic all through this code. For instance, checking for `NULL` doesn't make much sense, since there should never be a `NULL` in the circle. If you're trying to test the integrity of the list, do it carefully, not like this.

   This is the only place in the code where an endless loop can occur, so the problem really has to be here.

   Think carefully about what it means to sort a circular list, and what happens if you try to add an element that is either before all the others (in alphabetical order), or after all the others. This is where you hang.